# Com inserir textos em um gráfico de dispersão (com o ggplot)?

Tags: r, gráfico-de-dispersão

Olá, tenho um gráfico de dispersão em que combinei 6 variáveis no mesmo gráfico, agora estou tentando identificar cada variável no gráfico com o geom_text, mas consigo colocar o texto referente a apenas uma delas (Skull).  Alguém pode me ajudar? como faço para nomear as outras retas?

```
grafico_alometria_turF <- 
  ggplot(
         data = melted_dfF, 
         aes(
             x = alom_F_tur.CRC, 
             y = trait.value, 
             colour=as.factor(trait)
             )
   ) +
   geom_point(size= 2.5) + 
   geom_smooth(
              method = "lm", 
              se=FALSE, 
              aes(color= as.factor(trait)), 
              size= 1.3, 
              linetype= 1
   ) + 
   xlab("SVL") + 
   ylab("LOG Traits") + 
   theme_bw() + 
   ggtitle("D. turgida)") + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
   theme(legend.position="none") + 
   geom_text(
             x = 6.2, 
             y = 2.4, 
             label= "Skull",
             colour= "red"
   )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como postar uma parte dos seus dados? Pode ser com o resultado de `dput(head(melted_dfF))` para facilitar

Comment: Sim. Usei a função melt para criar um df onde uma das colunas, a coluna "traits" serviu como as.factor para que eu pudesse plotar todos as 6 variáveis (skull, maxilla, palatine....) no mesmo gráfico.                                                                           melted_dfF <- melt(df_alometriaF, id.vars = "alom_F_tur.CRC", variable.name = "trait", value.name = "trait.value")

Comment: structure(list(alom_F_tur.CRC = c(5.67675380226828, 5.89164421182577, 
6.02586597382531, 5.60947179518496, 5.90536184805457, 5.61312810638807
), trait = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("alom_F_tur.Skull_length", 
"alom_F_tur.Maxilla_length", "alom_F_tur.Palatine_length", "alom_F_tur.Pterygoid_length", 
"alom_F_tur.Mandible_length", "alom_F_tur.Dentary_length"), class = "factor"), 
    trait.value = c(2.287471455184, 2.484906649788, 2.53290284805626, 
    2.32727770558442, 2.44841554120559, 2.43097830776244)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o seguinte resolva o problema.
Primeiro cria-se um data.frame só com a linha correspondente ao valor máximo dos x. Depois um vetor de cores para cada linha desse df. E no `geom_text`, o argumento `data` toma o valor do novo df.

```
library(tidyverse)

text_dfF <- melted_dfF %>%
  group_by(trait) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = alom_F_tur.CRC) %>%
  mutate(trait = str_replace(trait, "^.*\\.([[:alpha:]]+)_.*$", "\\1"))

cores <- rainbow(length(text_dfF$trait))

melted_dfF %>%
  mutate(trait = str_replace(trait, "^.*\\.([[:alpha:]]+)_.*$", "\\1"),
         trait = factor(trait)) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = alom_F_tur.CRC, 
      y = trait.value, 
      colour = trait
    )
  ) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
  geom_smooth(
    formula = y ~ x,
    method = "lm", 
    se = FALSE, 
    aes(colour = trait), 
    size = 1.3, 
    linetype = 1
  ) + 
  geom_text(
    data = text_dfF,
    mapping = aes(
      x = alom_F_tur.CRC, 
      y = trait.value, 
      label= trait,
      colour = trait
    ),
    hjust = 1,
    vjust = -1,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cores) +
  xlab("SVL") + 
  ylab("LOG Traits") + 
  ggtitle("D. turgida") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "none")
```